# How to make project be opened in a particular perspective?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, perspective

I am developing a New Project Wizard as an Eclipse plug-in. I made it, but I don't know how to open it in particular perspective, say Java perspective. Any ideas on this?

Comment: I don't know but if you don't get an answer here try asking on #eclipse on Freenode (and be patient). It's the official IRC channel. You can access it via the web at http://webchat.freenode.net/.

Comment: Are you using the `org.eclipse.ui.newWizards` extension point?

Comment: @greg-449 Yes, I am using `org.eclipse.ui.newWizards` extension point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `org.eclipse.ui.newWizards` extension point has a `finalPerspective` argument where you can specify the id of the perspective you want opened at the end of project creation.